# How do I configure the package manager on server setup?

Tags: server, package-management

I am trying to install [ubuntu server 12.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)

 and there is a screen that comes up during the setup called "Configure the Package manager":

> If you need to use a HTTP proxy to access the outside world, enter the
>   proxy information here. Otherwise, leave this blank.
>
> The proxy information should be given in the standard form of
>   "http://[[user]@[:pass]@]host[:port]/".
>
> HTTP proxy information (blank for none):

I am not sure if "I need to use a HTTP proxy to access the outside world". How do I know?

**EDIT**

I am planning to use nginx as proxy to jetty, does this setup refers to that?

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely know if you were already using an HTTP proxy server for your Internet connection. Leave it blank and continue. This will have no effect on configuring your nginx proxy.